# Metamask Dapp Browser Not Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS on Certain Mobile Phones

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-5, https, metamask

I'm developing a web-based decentralized application (Dapp) that interacts with Ethereum using Metamask. I've noticed an issue with the Metamask Dapp browser on some mobile phones. When users type a URL with the http protocol instead of https, the Dapp browser does not automatically redirect to the secure https version of the website.

On most mobile phones, this redirection works as expected, but on a subset of devices, it doesn't. This behavior is causing a security concern as the application relies on HTTPS to ensure the confidentiality and integrity of data.

Here are some details:

- The web server is properly configured to handle both HTTP and HTTPS requests.
- The APP_URL in my Laravel application is set to use https in the .env file.
- The Metamask extension is up to date on all devices.

I'd like to understand why this issue is occurring and if there are any specific settings or configurations I need to adjust to ensure that the Metamask Dapp browser consistently redirects from HTTP to HTTPS on all mobile devices.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Metamask on mobile phones, and if so, how did you resolve it? Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.